# Atualizar dados em tempo Real sem refresh no blade - Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Gostaria de saber como  e qual é a melhor forma para atualizar dados em tempo real em uma tela utilizando Laravel.
A situação é a seguinte: Terei uma tela (de edição), que exibe os itens já incluídos nesta tela, porém terá a opção de adicionar mais um item. Após adicionar preciso que atualize os dados da tela (ou da div), sem recarregar a página. Exemplo:

```html
<div id="lista-servicos">
@foreach($servicos as $servico)
    <div class="servicos">
        <div class="servico-nome">{{ $servico->nome }}</div>
        <div class="valor-total"><span>R$</span>
          <span>{{$servico->valor</span>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
<a class="btn" id="adicionar-servico">Adicionar Serviços</a>
```

Se for clicado em adicionar serviços, e adicionar mais um... preciso que atualize o $servicos. Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo o que entendi você quer que o usuário selecione um único serviço por vez e a aplicação adicione na lista o serviço de forma assíncrona, certo?
Você pode criar uma rota que te retorne o serviço, consumir de forma assíncrona e depois criar as divs com JS.

Por exemplo crie uma rota que retorne um json com os serviços:

> /servico/5

Essa Rota deve retornar algo assim

{
"nome":"servico5"
"valor":"10.0"
}

Então se estiver usando JQuery você pode fazer o seguinte com a response:

```
const div_servicos = $("<div class="servicos"></div>");
div_servicos.append(`<div class="servico-nome">${response.nome}</div>`);
div_servicos.append(`<div class="valor-total"><span>R$</span><span>${servico.valor}</span></div>`);
$("#lista-servicos").append(div_servicos);
```

Comment: me ajudou amigo, obrigado.